# Synthesize speech from text in web app

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech, voice, speech

How can one synthesize speech in a web app?

Is there a way using the HTML5 Web Speech API?

For example, if I wanted to synthesize the sentence 'A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', how could I do that without playing a pre-recorded file of someone reading exactly that sentence

Comment: The specification is here: [Web Speech API Specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html). However, at the moment browsers do not support it out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is right now, the [SpeechSynthesis](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#tts-section) features which are part of the [Web Speech API Specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html)  have not been implemented in any browser yet.

However, you can have a look at [this Chrome extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tts.html).

EDIT:

It seems that the lastest Chrome Canary build might include the feature, however it only specifies that the feature has been started (http://www.chromestatus.com/features) and I was unable to find any more substantive information about it.

EDIT2:

As mentionned in the comments by @cdf, it seems that you can now play around with that feature by launching chrome with the `--enable-speech-synthesis` flag. Please see [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/X32NQBrDSYg/A0IGJCZ_jNwJ).

EDIT3:

This appears to be in Webkit now, but not on iOS at the moment. Not even in Chrome on iOS. **Demo** @BrandonAaskov

Comment: Ah, I see. Not even chrome canary?

Comment: @IMUXIxD, I updated the answer... it might actually, however the implementation is not finished yet.

Comment: Launch Chrome from the command line with the option --enable-speech-synthesis https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/X32NQBrDSYg/A0IGJCZ_jNwJ

Comment: This appears to be in Webkit now, but not on iOS at the moment. Not even in Chrome on iOS. http://jsbin.com/gosaqihi/9/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

That code works both on Chrome and on Safari (taken from my app [ttsreader](http://ttsreader.com)):

```
if (!('speechSynthesis' in window)) {
        // Synthesis not supported. 
            alert('Speech Synthesis is not supported by your browser. Switch to Chrome or Safari');
        }

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('hello world');
msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
msg.rate = 0.9; // 0.1 to 10
msg.pitch = 1; //0 to 2
msg.lang = "en-GB";
msg.text = "I will speak this out";
speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```